# How to perform the Lookup Multi-Touch gesture using Magic Mouse?

Tags: macos, mac, trackpad

I ofter use the Lookup Multi-Touch gesture while browsing the Internet using the three finger tap on my Trackpad. How to do the same using Magic Mouse?

Comment: Some Multi-Touch gestures that are available on the Trackpad  may not be available with the Magic Mouse. Have you looked in Mouse under System Preferences to see if it is available?

Comment: yeah i did check. It wasn't there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a third party utility such as [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/) or [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net/). I've mainly used the former as I've always felt it a bit more straight-forward when you just want to set up some minor extra functionality, but it hasn't been updated in a *very* long time and it feels like it gets buggier and buggier with each new OS X release.

BTT is definitely the way to go at this point, it has seen continued development and is really user friendly these days, and it's just incredibly powerful, once you've fiddled with it a bit and started to build up muscle memory you can get the Magic Mouse to do everything the trackpad does and much more.

In BetterTouchTool, select your mouse, and in the dropdown for predefined actions, choose "Lookup Word Under Cursor".

Answer (score 0):

I want to preview a web link by click the middle button of a mouse, I followed the answer by tolgraven and installed BetterTouchTool by `brew install bettertouchtool` in Terminal.

It can help me preview Safari link when I hover on a link and click middle mouse button on it.

Below are the settings for BetterTouchTool:

[image]